# How to connect reactjs with express api?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I had created a new react application and then installed express and body-parser and express-router,
 Now i want to connect a express Api to the application for event-driven application.

How do i connect it ?

Answer (score 1):

For API you make a different server using **Node.js** (**Express Framework**) and run on any port ex: 3000;

For Example your server run on : **http://localhost:3000/**

Now you can use **server api** in **React js** using **AXIOS**

Ref link for AXIOS : [Link](https://alligator.io/react/axios-react/)

Example to connect :

```
 axios.get('http://localhost:3000/users')
      .then(res => {
        const persons = res.data;
      })
```